# Rails 4: should tmp/cache be under version control?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I'm assuming no, since according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989256/can-the-rails-tmp-cache-assets-files-be-safely-deleted) it's unnecessary, but would there be any advantages (for example, when deploying to production) to keeping it in version control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tmp/cache` folder stores information about compiled css/js and sessions.

This files wouldn't be useful in production environment, since the assets are precompiled in a different way than the development.