# What is tmp directory for in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When [upgrading rails versions](https://makandracards.com/makandra/59328-how-to-upgrade-rails-workflow-advice#section-workflow-for-each-major-rails-upgrade-a) one instruction is:

> Clean out your tmp folder

I can see how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28492568/5783745).

Since I have never had cause to investigate this directory before, I am curious as to what it does? (that it how does it get used, so that I can eliminate any risks before clearing it). I am particularly concerned about deleting things:

[image]

(`development_secret.txt` has me concerned)

Comment: As per the development_secret.txt file, this is from the docs "The secret_key_base is used as the input secret to the application's key generator, which in turn is used to create all MessageVerifiers/MessageEncryptors, including the ones that sign and encrypt cookies.

In development and test, this is randomly generated and stored in a temporary file in tmp/development_secret.txt.", so you might safely delete it.

Nowadays the tmp/ folder can hold a lot of garbage generated from the frontend, so you might want to check that.

Comment: Another file is the created by the command `bin/rails dev:cache`, so if you need cache active in development you might want to run the command again after the cleanup.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thank you. I deleted the whole directory (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989297/5783745)) and it seems the necessary bits regenerate with the next `rails server` command. Thanks again for your help